# UIKeyboard first character is capital in simulator but not in device?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I am creating ViewBased Project, Just in ViewController's ViewDidLoad, I am writting the following code

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

UITextField *name_textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 21, 200, 30)];
name_textField.delegate=self;
name_textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
name_textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[name_textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[name_textField resignFirstResponder];
[self.view addSubview:name_textField];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

As I do run on simulator, it will show first character capital in textField and also shift key is press, but as I run it on device (iPod Touch 4g, iOS 5), it is not doing any capitalization.

It is strange behavior, can any one tell me reasons and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this after initialization:

```
name_textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
```

Comment: Sorry but it is also not working, I check Word and Sentence Types, There is no other code, it is fine in simulator, but in device,it is having issue

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that the "Auto-Capitalization" option is turned off on that device. You can find that option in Settings > General > Keyboard.

Comment: It definitely is this option.